# Combining multiple CSVs using MLCP?

Tags: marklogic

I have a question about MLCP, I know there is a way to break up
nested structure XML into separated XML document.
Is there OOTB feature to create nested structure XML from
multiple CSVs as a input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write your own data transformation in XQuery or SJS which will process incoming data for you. However, it is not possible for MLCP to work with more than one CSV row at a time. You might be able to get creative and use `cts:search` or similar to find existing documents that should be merged within your MLCP transformation. Yet, it would be tough to make that work perfectly due to the intricacies of concurrent data insertion.

You could try to do some data wrangling outside of MarkLogic. For example, if the CSV comes from an RDBMS, you could change the query generating it to return the denormalized form you want.

Or you could embrace MarkLogic's ELT strategy where you load your data exactly as it is and then run processes to transform your data once it's inside MarkLogic. The [DataHub Framework](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/data-hub-framework) is especially helpful for managing complex data transformation processes like these.

Comment: I have done this with custom MLCP transforms many times. Make sure to load the data you like to embed first, and use `fn:doc`, `cts:search` or `cts:values` to pull in whatever you need to embed.

Comment: In case you have many sources, and you'd like to merge them together, that does sound like a good match for datahub though. It comes with the notion of loading partial data into a Staging environment first, and then Harmonizing it while merging into the Final environment.